# Changing resolved status to Closed status for a user story in Jira

Tags: jira

I am using Jira for organizing user stories for my project on Agile approach. When I tried to close a user story it shows the status as ' Resolved', rather than 'Closed'.
Can someone help me how to change the user story status to closed?

Please post your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 5):

Its a bit hard to answer such a vague question - so if you can ellaborate a bit on the customization you have done in your JIRA instance, it can help.

Some pointers:

JIRA is using workflows to manage the flow an issue can use.
The default workflow that comes with an installation of JIRA is called "jira" and looks like this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow

Depending on the customization of your JIRA installation, you can either change the workflow to go from Open to Closed when you use the "Resolve" operation.

If you are not the JIRA administrator, different workflow transitions can have various properties and conditions and validators set on them, for example checking for permissions. So if you are a user that does not have permissions to do a certain transition - you can see if you can change it via the permissions administation panel, or again - in the workflow validations.